# C++ taking string from user and adding it to the end of a file

Tags: file, input, char

I want to take a sentence from a user and add it to the end of a file. 
The sentence will contain a name, a height and a weight. It's for calculating BMIs.

```
[name] [height] [weight]
```

So, I do this:

```
void write(){
fstream writing ("data.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::ate); // write to
                                            //end of file because file has data in it
if (writing.is_open())
{
    string input;
    cout << "Enter some data: name height weight\n";
    char space_checker = _getch(); // using _getch() with <conio.h>
    while (space_chcker != 13) { // char value of enter is 13
        getline(cin,input);
        writing << user_input;
        check = _getch();
    }
}
```

When the user goes to type something in, it ignores the first two keystrokes - they don't register. What is going wrong here?

The first and second instance of `_getch()` is causing the keystroke problem, anyway to fix this?

Comment: What specifically is going wrong? Is an exception raised? Is it not compiling at all? Does it initially appear to work, but in the end not actually behave as intended? Without a clearer idea of *how* it is not working for you, it will be difficult to provide an answer.

Comment: @eestrada updated with complete question, sorry.

Comment: No worries. I just wanted to make sure your question was complete so that you can get the answer that you need. :)